# How to embed existing example from GitHub into my markdown documentation using Znai

Tags: groovy, markdown, documentation, znai

I document usage of my API and want to refer to other people examples from GitHub repositories.

How do I include content of a file from GitHub into my documentation using Znai?

Answer (score 0):

In [Znai](https://github.com/testingisdocumenting/znai) you can specify lookup locations inside `lookup-paths` file. One of the supported locations is HTTP location like in this example:  https://testingisdocumenting.org/znai/flow/lookup-paths#http-lookup-location

For example, to include a content from a repo I have following entry in my lookup-paths file

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/testingisdocumenting/webtau/master
```

Once `lookup-paths` is set, use [include-file](https://testingisdocumenting.org/znai/snippets/external-code-snippets) plugin and embedded a file content from the repo

```
:include-file: webtau-data/src/main/java/org/testingisdocumenting/webtau/data/Data.java
```

Or use other plugins like [include-groovy](https://testingisdocumenting.org/znai/snippets/groovy) to extract a specific method body

```
:include-groovy: webtau-data/src/test/groovy/org/testingisdocumenting/webtau/data/DataCsvTest.groovy {
  entry: "validateTestCsvTable"
}
```

```
table.should == ['id' | 'absolute' | 'number' | 'comment'] {
                _______________________________________________
                'id1' | 'yes'      | '12'     | 'what can you say'
                'id2' | 'no'       | '24'     | 'fourth' }
```